# Silverstripe TreeDropDownField is showing (none) in translation

Tags: silverstripe

I am using SilverStripe 3.1.2.
A page has a $has_one to SiteTree and the TreeDropdownField is implemented like this:

```
$firstOfferBoxLink = new TreeDropdownField(
    'FirstOfferBoxLinkID', _t('General.FIRST_OFFER_BOX_LINK', 'First offer box link'), 'SiteTree'
);
$fields->insertBefore($firstOfferBoxLink, 'FirstOfferBoxImage');
```

In the default language this is working like it should, but in translations of the page it just shows:

"Link    (none)"
I have tried following the instructions on the github repo (found [here](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable/blob/master/docs/en/index.md)), for example with the following line after all the normal fields but before the TreeDropDownFields:

```
$this->applyTranslatableFieldsUpdate($fields, 'updateCMSFields');
```

Nothing changes.

Has someone got any idea, how to get TreeDropDownFields to work in translations?

Comment: have you added the Translatable extension to the class SiteTree or to class Page?

Comment: Yes, I added:
`SiteTree::add_extension('Translatable');` in the _config.php